# Passing --out-format=FMT argument to rsync from Bourne shell script

Tags: osx, rsync, bourne-shell

I'm trying to execute `rsync` from a Bourne shell script (read: Bash extensions not available) and after lots of searching, single/double quotes combinations, escapes, etc, I wasn't able to correctly pass the `--out-format='%n'` argument.

For example, this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

(set -x ; $(rsync -auh --delete --out-format='%n' "$1" "$2")) || exit 1
```

when invoked like `./myscript.sh dir1/ dir2/` returns this output on MacOS 10.12.6:

```
++ rsync -auh --delete --out-format=%n dir1/ dir2/
+ ./ file1.c file1.h file2.c file2.h
myscript.sh: line 3: ./: is a directory
```

where `file1.c` `file1.h` `file2.c` and `file2.h` are the contents of `dir1/`

First of all, I have no idea on why the `+ ./ file1.c file1.h file2.c file2.h` line is output, because `--out-format='%n'` outputs one file per line, and not all files on the same line. Also, the mysterious starting `./` seems to be the cause (or the consequence) of the error.

If I remove `--out-format='%n'` from the script, then it runs fine, with no errors.

If I execute the command from the terminal, it runs fine both with single quotes in the argument and without them (`--out-format='%n'` and `--out-format=%n`). When on the script, it fails the same in both cases.

What could be causing this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running the `rsync` command in a command substitution. A command substitution will be replaced by the output of the command within it, and the way your script is written, this output will be executed as a command, which is why you get that error message and the seemingly weird tracing output.

Instead:

```sh
#!/bin/sh -x

rsync -auh --delete --out-format='%n' "$1" "$2" || exit 1
```

If you still want the `set -x` in a subshell within your script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

( set -x; rsync -auh --delete --out-format='%n' "$1" "$2" ) || exit 1
```

The `exit 1` could possibly be dropped if the `rsync` is the last command in the script as the exit status of the script would be the exit status of the last command executed, unless you want to force it to be *exactly* 1 no matter how `rsync` failed.

Comment: How true! :-( A consequence of copy'n'paste when I didn't rest for too long! Thanks!!